# Linking project and framework paths netbeans PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, hyperlink, project

I am trying to develop an OpenCart module. I've done this already but now, I would like to have different paths for developing it more comfortable:

I would like to have the OpenCart installation (as it were a framework or whatever) with all its files in a different path and have my little module in another path. Is there any way to "import" all OpenCart files when running the project?

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to your include path, that way it will see the install but not be in the same path as your project.

Go to your project in the project explorer, expand to see folder 'include path' > right click > properties > PHP Include Path > Add Folder.

Comment: I've done it already, but when I run the project it does not load the included path

Comment: afaik include path is used for code completion, not for loading source files. Perhaps you can use some autoloading to load your files as such